# Does oracle attempt to rerun a failed job automatically? Where can I see the setting for the same?

Tags: database, oracle, scheduler, jobs

This is about the jobs scheduled in Oracle , the ones we can configure and see in the table user_scheduler_jobs.

You can see the screenshot showing the Properties of the job below. I have masked some of the data.

[Job Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg2el.png)

One property **NLS_ENV** is not visible completely in the screenshot so I am pasting the details below for that property.

```
NLS_LANGUAGE='AMERICAN' NLS_TERRITORY='AMERICA' NLS_CURRENCY='$' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY='AMERICA' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,' NLS_CALENDAR='GREGORIAN' NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='AMERICAN' NLS_SORT='BINARY' NLS_TIME_FORMAT='HH.MI.SSXFF AM' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM' NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT='HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR' NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR' NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY='$' NLS_COMP='BINARY' NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS='BYTE' NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP='FALSE'
```

So , one of the Database jobs (a scheduled one) failed recently and it ran immediately and showed a successful status. In short , the job ran twice around the same time with 1failure and 1 successful attempt.

I am trying to understand what could have happened here. Like , how come the job ran 2nd time automatically?

Does Oracle attempt to rerun a failed job automatically? Where can I see the setting for the same in my Oracle database?

Please guide.

Comment: it could depend on how the job is set up. can you post the DDL for the job configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the job details to the original post. You can check now.

Comment: `RESTARTABLE` is set to`FALSE`. Try using `dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('jobname', 'restartable', TRUE);`

Comment: @TenG, As RESTARTABLE is set to FALSE, I am wondering how come Oracle attempted another run after the failure.